# How to time a function in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

My code is as under:

**HTML**

```
<section ng-controller="randController as rand">
      Skriv inn minimumtall:<br>
      <input ng-model="rand.minimum" type="number" placeholder="Minste tall"><br>
      <div class="tiny"></div>
      Skriv inn makstall:<br>
      <input ng-model="rand.maksimum" type="number" placeholder="Største tall"><br><br>
      <ul class="nav nav-pills" ng-controller="clickController as click">
          <li ng-click="click.randClick()" ng-class="{'active' : click.randCheck(true)}" >
              <a ng-click="rand.tilfeldig()">Randomize!</a>
          </li>
      </ul>
      <div class="tiny"></div><br>
      <pre>Tilfeldig tall = {{rand.tilfeldig()}}</pre>
</section>
```

**JS**

```
.controller('clickController', function ($timeout) {
  this.randClicked = false;
  this.randClick = function () {
    this.randClicked = true;
    $timeout(function() {
        this.randClicked = false;
    }, 1000, true);
  };
  this.randCheck = function (x) {
      return this.randClicked === x;
  };
})
```

What I am trying to do is to reset the active class of the `<li>`-element after about 2 seconds (Unclick it after it has been clicked for 2 seconds). I have gotten tips from forum members but it still doesn't work. Currently, I get [this error](https://goo.gl/ktVqcq), which I don't understand.

Comment: Have you looked at setTimeout and setInterval?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/729921/settimeout-or-setinterval

Answer (score 2):

There is a problem about `this` pointer in your code. Try this:

```
.controller('clickController', function ($timeout) {
  var that = this;
  this.randClicked = false;
  this.randClick = function () {
    this.randClicked = true;
    $timeout(function() {
        that.randClicked = false;
    }, 1000, true);
  };
  this.randCheck = function (x) {
      return this.randClicked === x;
  };
})
```

Comment: This soulotion workes, although it doesn't always work. However it seems very odd to me. If `that` equals `this`, why is it a problem to use `this`?

Comment: Update: this soulotion only works when the input boxes are empty. (Couldn't edit last comment because I'm on mobile)

Comment: @tjespe `this` pointer is one of most tricky parts of javascript. It's not quite simple as it looks like. Search some relevant articles and read carefully. It deserve spending 10 mins, I promise.

Comment: The button works quite well now, but I wouldn't like the random number to be recalculated 0.2 seconds after the button is clicked. Do you have any idea why that is?

Comment: No. It's out of topic of this question. Please post another question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use angulars $timeout function for this.

First you have to inject it into your controller like so:

```
.controller('clickController', function ($timeout) {
```

Then you can use it like this

```
this.randClick = function () {
  this.randClicked = true;
  $timeout(function() {
    this.randClicked = false;
  }, 2000)
};
```

Where 2000 is the amount you want to wait before executing the code inside, in milliseconds

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this. But I wonder: why is there a $-sign in front of timeout? Or more generally: what purpose does the $-sign serve in angular?

Comment: Generally the $-sign signifies it's an angular function and not native Javascript. $timeout is basically like setTimeout but it will $digest afterwards I believe, so it will update all bindings and such.

Comment: @tjespe As per the angular documentation: `The $ prefix is there to namespace Angular-provided services. To prevent collisions it's best to avoid naming your services and models anything that begins with a $.`

Comment: The suggested answer has not solved my problem. The class of the `<li>`-element stays active. However, the random number output changes after a second (this is not wanted though)

Comment: Can you try to add `, true` after 2000, it shouldn't matter but sometimes its  necessary

Comment: I tried adding `, true` after 1000. It still doesn't work. [This](https://goo.gl/ktVqcq) is the error I get, but I can't make any sense out of it.